# How to integrate 3rd python module into a C console program

Tags: python, c, arm

I have a C console program in a **armv7** platform. 
It has a main.c file that's like:

```
#include <Python/Python.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
    PyRun_SimpleString("execfile('hello.py')");
    return 0;
}
```

I would use SciPy in the hello.py, but SciPy contains .c files.

I wish to compile those .c files and my main.c into one executable file.

How can I do that?

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem.  What do you hope to accomplish by doing as you describe?

Comment: Tks for you quick reply. I hope to enhance my iOS app by executing python scripts and I hope to use some 3rd python module such as SciPy, OpenCV and scikit-learn in that scripts.